# Sorting on multiple column header in liferay searchcontainer

Tags: liferay-6

i done with sorting on single column header of liferay searchcontainer in liferay 6.0.6.
now i want to apply sorting on multiple fields i.e FirstName,LastName,Date either in asc or desc order.
can anybody help me out..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you be a little more clear. Do you want sort by multiple columns like sort by firstName desc then sort by lastName asc then by modifiedDate asc or you just want that sort should appear on all the header columns and on click of each the previous sort is lost and it will sort according to the new sort?

Comment: i done with my prob.....

Comment: So can you if possible for the benefit of the community answer your own question and if possible edit the question to make it more clear? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**view.jsp**

```
<%
PortalPreferences portalPrefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortalPreferences(request);
String orderByCol = ParamUtil.getString(request, "orderByCol");
String orderByType = ParamUtil.getString(request, "orderByType");
System.out.println("Col  "+ orderByCol);


if (Validator.isNotNull(orderByCol) && Validator.isNotNull(orderByType)) {
portalPrefs.setValue("NAME_SPACE", "order-by-col", orderByCol);
portalPrefs.setValue("NAME_SPACE", "order-by-type", orderByType);

} else {

orderByCol = portalPrefs.getValue("NAME_SPACE", "order-by-col", "Date");
orderByType = portalPrefs.getValue("NAME_SPACE", "order-by-type", "asc");

}
 %>


 <liferay-ui:search-container  delta='20' emptyResultsMessage="No Form Submitted" orderByCol="<%= orderByCol %>" orderByType="<%= orderByType %>">

 <liferay-ui:search-container-results>

<%
            List<User> userList = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(-1,-1);
            OrderByComparator orderByComparator =       
           CustomComparatorUtil.getUserOrderByComparator(orderByCol, orderByType);        

           Collections.sort(userList,orderByComparator);

          results = ListUtil.subList(userList, searchContainer.getStart(),   
                     searchContainer.getEnd());

               if (userList.size()< total)
                {total = userList.size();
                }

               pageContext.setAttribute("results", results);
               pageContext.setAttribute("total", total);

 %>


 </liferay-ui:search-container-results>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
     className="com.liferay.portal.model.User"

     modelVar="user">

     <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
      name="Screen Name"
      property="screenName"
      orderable="<%= true %>"
      orderableProperty="screenName"
     />

      <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
      name="Email"
      property="emailAddress"
      orderable="<%= true %>"
     orderableProperty="emailAddress"
     />

      <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
      name="Date"
      property="createDate"
      orderable="<%= true %>"

     />


   </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

**CustomComparatorUtil**

```
public static OrderByComparator getUserOrderByComparator(
               String orderByCol, String orderByType) {


               boolean orderByAsc = false;

               if (orderByType.equals("asc")) {
               orderByAsc = true;
               }

               OrderByComparator orderByComparator = null;

                System.out.println("Custom "+ orderByCol);
               if (orderByCol.equalsIgnoreCase("screenName")) {
                   System.out.println("1");
                orderByComparator = new FirstNameComparator(orderByAsc);
               }
               else if (orderByCol.equalsIgnoreCase("emailAddress")) {
                   System.out.println("2");
                orderByComparator = new EmailComparator(orderByAsc);
               }
               else if (orderByCol.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
                 System.out.println("3");
                orderByComparator = new DateComparator(orderByAsc);
               }/*
               else if (orderByCol.equalsIgnoreCase("Job Title")) {

                orderByComparator = new JobTitleComparator(orderByAsc);
               }*/

               return orderByComparator;
               }
```

**FirstNameComparator**

public static String ORDER_BY_ASC = "status ASC";

```
 public static String ORDER_BY_DESC = "status DESC";


  public FirstNameComparator()
  {
   this(false);
  }

  public FirstNameComparator(boolean asc) {
   _asc = asc;
  }

 public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {

   User instance1 = (User) obj1;
   User instance2 = (User) obj2;

   int value = instance1.getFirstName().toLowerCase().compareTo(instance2.getFirstName().toLowerCase());

   if(_asc)
   {
    return value;
   } else
   {
    return -value;
   }

 }


 public String getOrderBy() {

  if (_asc) {
   return ORDER_BY_ASC;
  }
  else {
   return ORDER_BY_DESC;
  }
  }

 private boolean _asc;
```

}

similarly u can make class for emailaddress and date..

Comment: This solution doesn't use database ordering, so if table contains a lot of data this solution would kill database and app. server.